# Error Exporting Model as gltf

Tags: python, export, gltf, three.js

When I try to export my blender file as a gltf, I get this error. I tried exporting it without animations and I still get the error. I suspect it's because I imported something from sketchfab into this project? Not sure though. I'm still new to blender.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are quite a few posts here about errors exporting to GLTF. Type 'gltf export error' (without the quotes) into the search field at the top of this page and see if one applies to your case.